# Querying a Created View

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with a textbook exercise.

I have the following relation:

[image]

I need to:

[image]

My attempt at this is:

```
CREATE VIEW district_stats AS
   SELECT district, COUNT(customer_id)
   FROM dv_customer, dv_address
   WHERE ...
```

I'm really confused on what to do here. After I create this view, I need to query this view to find Which district has the least number of customers (Query from the district stats view).

I am not sure how to query the view, but I was able to create a query (I think) where it will return the district with the least amount of customers given all of the relations:

[image]

Comment: Can you include text instead of screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You should alias the COUNT(customer_id) in your view to something like "customer_count".  The final view creation will look similar to

```
CREATE VIEW district_stats AS
   SELECT district, COUNT(customer_id) as customer_count
   FROM dv_customer, dv_address
   WHERE dv_customer.address_id = dv_address.address_id
   GROUP BY district;
```

Querying from a view is the same as querying from a table.  The query to get the district with the lowest customer count would be...

```
SELECT district
  FROM district_stats
 ORDER BY customer_count ASC LIMIT 1;
```